# DataTable label inside record type - compile error

Tags: types, datatable, f#

I declare the following type in F# with a DataTable type label inside.
It does not compile when the record y is created, with the error message "*The type 'DTTest' is not defined*"

```
type DTTest = {
    dt:DataTable        
}

let y:DTTest = { //compile error
    dt = null
}
```

Works with various other types of course:

```
type DTTest = {
    dt:DateTime        
}

let y:DTTest = { //compiles
    dt = DateTime.MinValue
}
```

What is the reason that `DataTable` causes a compile error here? Are there any other types that cannot be used inside a record type?

Comment: There shouldn't be such a restriction.  Both should be OK.  Maybe you didn't have a namespace open?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `DataTable` specifically. There are no types that cannot be used in a record. Are you using any IDE? Do you get any complaints from it? Do you get any compiler warnings or other errors? Are you sure you have opened the namespace where `DataTable` is defined? Are you sure you are referencing the right assembly?

Comment: Nope. I have opened System.Data namespace after adding System.Data dll as reference. I am using VS 2013.

Comment: Well, this got resolved after adding System.Xml dll reference which was not present earlier. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, this should work fine.

You can get an error if you do not open the `System.Data` namespace:

```
> type DTTest = { dt:DataTable }
  let y:DTTest = { dt = null }
  ;;
stdin(5,20): error FS0039: The type 'DataTable' is not defined
```

Or you can get another error if `DataTable` is a type you defined in F# and it does not allow `null`:

```
> type DataTable = (...)
  type DTTest = { dt:DataTable }
  let y:DTTest = { dt = null }
  ;;
stdin(5,20): error FS0043: The type 'DataTable' does not have 'null' as a proper value
```

I think the only situation in which you'd get a message saying *`DTTest` is not defined* is if you use F# Interactive in some unexpected way. For example, if you restart F# Interactive and select the line with `let y:DTTest = { .. }` and run it, you will get an error, because F# Interactive does not automatically load all the necessary definitions - you have to evaluate those yourself first.